# C++ Arduino - initialise a 2D array of characters

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, character

In Arduino C++ I'm trying to initialise a 2 dim array of characters.

At each 1st level element of the array will be two 2nd level elements, the first being one character (plus the assumed \0 terminator) the second being a maximum of nineteen characters (plus the assumed \0 terminator). Thus each 1st level element should have no more than twenty two characters - 1 (+1) + 19 (+1).

I'm trying:

```
char Mchar[][22] = {
{" ","0000000"},
{"A","10111"},
{"B","111010101"},
{"C","11101011101"},
{"D","1110101"},
{"E","1"},
{"F","101011101"},
{"G","111011101"},
{"H","1010101"},
{"I","101"},
{"J","1011101110111"},
{"K","111010111"},
{"L","101110101"},
{"M","1110111"},
{"N","11101"},
{"O","11101110111"},
{"P","10111011101"},
{"Q","1110111010111"},
{"R","1011101"},
{"S","10101"},
{"T","111"},
{"U","1010111"},
{"V","101010111"},
{"W","101110111"},
{"X","11101010111"},
{"Y","1110101110111"},
{"Z","11101110101"},
{"0","1110111011101110111"},
{"1","10111011101110111"},
{"2","101011101110111"},
{"3","1010101110111"},
{"4","10101010111"},
{"5","101010101"},
{"6","11101010101"},
{"7","1110111010101"},
{"8","111011101110101"},
{"9","11101110111011101"},
{".","10111010111010111"},
{","",1110111010101110111"},
{"?","101011101110101"},
{"'","1011101110111011101"},
{"!","1110101110101110111"},
{"/","1110101011101"},
{"(","111010111011101"},
{")","1110101110111010111"},
{"&","10111010101"},
{":","11101110111010101"},
{";","11101011101011101"},
{"=","1110101010111"},
{"+","1011101011101"},
{"-","111010101010111"},
{"_","10101110111010111"},
{"\"","101110101011101"},
{"$","10101011101010111"},
{"@","10111011101011101"}
};
```

Needless to say, it's not working for me, getting repeated error lines of:

> error: too many initializers for ‘char [22]’

Would someone care to point out the error of my ways.

TIA

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: There is still a single initializer expected for the `[22]` part. This syntax is simply not accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The initialization syntax for this is unclear and probably wrong, you are trying to initialize an array of characters (a string) with a curly brace delimited list of two individual strings (which should be used to initialize an array (among other things) of strings).  If you have access to `std::vector`, `std::string` and `std::pair` do this instead

```
auto vec = std::vector<std::pair<char, std::string>>{
    {' ', "0000000"},
    {'A', "10111"},
    {'B', "111010101"},
    {'C', "11101011101"}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is an array of 22 char arrays. So that gives you one list of strings. But you seem to want a list of string pairs. For that I think you need `3` dimensions:

```
char Mchar[][2][22] = {
    {" ","0000000"},
    {"A","10111"},
    {"B","111010101"},
    {"C","11101011101"},
    {"D","1110101"},
    // ...
};
```

Alternatively you could create an array of pairs of `char const*` like this:

```
char const* Mchar[][2] = {
    {" ","0000000"},
    {"A","10111"},
    {"B","111010101"},
    {"C","11101011101"},
    {"D","1110101"},
    // ...
};
```

Now your strings can be any length because your array only stores the pointers to their first elements.

**EDIT**

On re-reading the question, what you are literally asking for would be this:

```
char Mchar[][22] = {
    {" 0000000"},
    {"A10111"},
    {"B111010101"},
    {"C11101011101"},
    {"D1110101"},
    // ...
};
```